# No such module 'Firebase' - Xcode and Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to incorporate Firebase Analytics into my SwiftUI project in Xcode.  I've added the Firebase package using Swift Package Manager, and am able to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` to initialize my app in my `UIApplicationDelegate` class.  Now I'm trying to log analytics events and am running into an issue.

My `UIApplicationDelegate` class is in an iOS-specific folder.  I have a service class that is in a Shared folder (to be used across both iOS and macOS builds).  In my service class, I've added a line that says:

```
import Firebase
```

However, when I go to build my iOS target I get an error saying:

```
No such module 'Firebase'
```

I don't know why this import statement would cause a problem, since I have the very same statement in my `UIApplicationDelegate` class.  The only thing I could think of was that somehow my Shared classes don't know about Firebase?  Maybe?  When I view the iOS target in my project it shows that the `FirebaseCrashlytics` and `FirebaseAnalytics` frameworks have been added to it.

I'm at a loss as to what's happening.  All other things I've found online are for Cocoapods, which I'm not using for dependency management.  I'm leveraging the Swift Package Manager for this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Might be an Xcode project metadata issue.  A clean build or removal of DerivedData might help

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I've tried that numerous times.  Clean...  Build...  Clean...  Remove DerivedData...  Build...  Same behavior.

Comment: Rather than using Xcode's interface, I'd look directly at your Package.swift and make sure that the Firebase dependency is added for you iOS target. Sounds like it might just be added for the macOS one, but Xcode's interface isn't great at multi-target setups like this.

Comment: Using Xcode's SPM GUI doesn't result in a Package.swift file.  Is there another way?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/discussions/9105

Comment: Yes, I've done all that.  The package is listed as being a linked framework for my iOS target.  When I build, however, Xcode seems to disagree.

Answer (score 13):

After installing the Firebase swift package, make sure you add the Firebase libraries to Frameworks:

TARGETS -> Your App -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content -> hit '+' to add the Firebase libraries you want:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but the post below from GitHub should fix it:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9014#issuecomment-979489434

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33001067)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but with 'FirebaseCore'. I tried everything, but what worked for me was to add `@_implementationOnly` to import. So it should look like this:

```
@_implementationOnly import FirebaseCore
```

[Here is the link that helped me](https://forums.swift.org/t/issue-with-third-party-dependencies-inside-a-xcframework-through-spm/41977/2) and it says:

> You could use @_implementationOnly import for the modules from the
> third-party SDK if you aren't using anything from that SDK as part of
> your module's public interface.